# Optimizing group by with data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I'm wondering what is the efficient way to reuse some calculation on one column for the other columns when I use `group by`. Here is a simplified example:

```
dt = data.table(iris)
dt[,.(
  # .N, 
  # sum_len = sum(Sepal.Length), 
  avg_len   = sum(Sepal.Length)/.N,
  var_len   = sum(Sepal.Length^2)/.N - (sum(Sepal.Length)/.N)^2
),by=  "Species"]
```

here I need to reuse `sum(Sepal.Length)` and `.N` without recalculating.

EDIT:
a more complete example is when we are using `.SD` as well:

```
dt[,c(lapply(.SD, mean),lapply(.SD, var)),by="Species",.SDcols = c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width")]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to use `{}` and create the summarised variable first ('tmp'), then uses that for further calculations

```
dt[, {
         tmp <- sum(Sepal.Length)/.N
         tmp2 <- sum(Sepal.Length^2)/.N 
        .(avg_len = tmp, var_len = tmp2 -(tmp)^2)
     }, 
        by = Species]
#     Species avg_len  var_len
#1:     setosa   5.006 0.121764
#2: versicolor   5.936 0.261104
#3:  virginica   6.588 0.396256
```

Note that

```
tmp <- sum(Sepal.Length)/.N
tmp2 <- sum(Sepal.Length^2)/.N
```

is equal to

```
tmp <- mean(Sepal.Length)
tmp2 <- mean(Sepal.Length^2)
```

Comment: awesome, thanks. that's it. What about when we are using `.SD` in data.table.
`dt[,lapply(.SD, var),by="Species",.SDcols = c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width")]
`

Comment: that is about 15% faster than the original on 10k stacked iris on my laptop

Comment: I can confirm that this is indeed quicker, but also that using the `mean` function seems to make it a bit slower actually.

Comment: @MahdiJadaliha  You can create a function based on this and then apply it on `lapply(.SD, f1)` where `f1 <- function(x) {x1 <- sum(x)/.N; x2 <- sum(x^2)/.N; list(avg_len = x1, var_len = x2 - (x1)^2)}` and when you do `lapply` wrap with `unlist`, and `recursive = FALSE`